# How to derive $(x,y)$ of clothoid curve from $rl=A^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Clothoid curve is described by $rl=A^2$, where
$r$ is turning radius and $l$ is length from the origin.
(This definition is very intuitive to understand for me)

Also it's known that the coordinate $(x,y)$ is described as following.

$x(l) = \int_0^l \cos(s^2)ds$,  $y(l) = \int_0^l \sin(s^2)ds$

But how can I derive these equations from $rl=A^2$ ?

I searched a hint but I wasn't able to get, probably because it's too obvious for other people. Thanks.