# Show that: a) $X^{-1}(t)$ is bounded in $[\beta,\infty)$. b)No system solution approaches zero solution when $t \rightarrow \infty.$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Let a system $x' = A(t)x$ and suppose there are values positives $k, \beta$ such that a positive fundamental matrix $X(t)$ satisfies

$\|X(t)\| \leq k$, $t \geq \beta$ and

$$ \liminf_{t \rightarrow \infty} \int^t_\beta \operatorname{tr}(A(s))\,ds > - \infty.$$

Show that:

a)$X^{-1}(t)$ is bounded in $[\beta,\infty)$.

b)No system solution approaches zero solution when $t \rightarrow \infty.$

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a "positive fundamental mantrix".  Care to explicate?

Comment: Maybe you mean to say $\det X(t) > 0$; is that right?  Cheers!

Comment: Being fundamental matrix means that the matrix is solution and $detX(t) \neq 0$

Comment: Yes, I understand what "fundamental matrix" means; it's the "positive" I'm curious about!  Cheers!

Comment: Usually ODEs like that have $x(t)$ a vector, not a matrix. Anyway, perhaps the problem wants you to solve the ODE using a matrix exponential, and then apply the det-matrix-trace formula here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential

Comment: @Michael:  but for time-dependent $A(t)$, we cannot in general write $A(t) = e^{B(t)}$.  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis , I believe the general solution for $t \geq \beta$ is $x(t) = e^{\int_{\beta}^t A(s)ds} x(\beta)$.

Comment: Note also that if $x(t)$ is a solution then $x(t)M$ is also a solution for any matrix $M$ of appropriate size.  If $x(\beta)$ is invertible then we can get any desired initial condition $y(\beta)$ by using $M = x(\beta)^{-1}y(\beta)$.

Comment: @Michael:  $x(t) = e^{\int_\beta^t A(s)ds} x(\beta)$ only works when $[A(t), \int_\beta^t A(s)ds] = 0$.  For a detailed explanation, see my answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718613/proving-nonhomogeneous-ode-is-bounded/732147#732147

Comment: @RobertLewis , well I never liked matrix exponentials and have never actually used them.  I do not understand what you mean by $[A(t), \int_{\beta}^t A(s)ds] = 0$, to me that looks like both entries in a matrix must be 0, so $A(t)=0$.  Nevertheless I differentiated by hand an $A(t)^2$ matrix and found indeed the result is not always $2A(t)A'(t)$ nor $2A'(t)A(t)$.  So likely you are right that $e^{\int_{\beta}^t A(s)ds} x(\beta)$ does not always work.  It does seem to work when $A(t) = g(t)A$ for some scalar function $g(t)$, which does not require $A(t)$ to be identically zero.

Comment: For example if one says that $[x,y] =0$ that would usually be interpreted as $x=0$ and $y=0$.  I have no idea what else it could mean.

Comment: @Michael:  by $[C, D]$ I mean the commutator or Lie bracket of the two matrices $C, D$:  $[C, D] = CD - DC$!  Saying $[C, D] = 0$ is another way of saying $C$ and $D$ commute, $CD = DC$! Cheeeeers!

Comment: @Michael If you’re interpreting that as a matrix, I believe it would be written without a comma, as $[x \; y]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll present a solution to this problem in several steps, and try to give links/citings/references for any specialized outside results I may use.

I assume throughout that $A(t)$ is a continuous, real matrix function of $t$, and that $\text{size}(A) = n$.

***Some Notation, Definitons, etc:*** The following solution applies to real differential equations of the form

$x' = A(t)x; \tag{1}$

that is, we take $A(t) \in M_n(\Bbb R)$ for all $t$ in the domain of definition of $A(t)$, and correspondingly $x(t) \in \Bbb R^n$; we will also assume the the notation $\langle u, v \rangle$ refers to the standard inner product on $\Bbb R^n$; thus, $\langle u, v \rangle$ denotes the euclidean inner product $\sum_1^n u_i v_i$; here the $u_i, v_i \in \Bbb R$ are as usual the components of $u, v$; we furthermore denote the *standard basis* on $\Bbb R^n$ by $\mathbf e_i$; thus

$\mathbf e_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \tag{2}$

$\mathbf e_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \tag{3}$

and so forth, on down to

$\mathbf e_n = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}; \tag{4}$

note that

$\Vert \mathbf e_k \Vert = 1, 1 \le k \le n. \tag{5}$

Finally, we will take $\Vert T \Vert$ to be the standard *operator norm* for $T \in M_n(\Bbb R)$; thus, among other equivalent definitions, we have

$\Vert T \Vert = \sup_{\Vert u \Vert = 1} \Vert Tu \Vert, \tag{6}$

where of course

$\Vert u \Vert = \sqrt{\langle u, u \rangle} \tag{7}$

for $u \in \Bbb R^n$.

These preliminary remarks being made, we continue as follows:

Before proceeding with the analytics of the solution *per se*, we will develop a result which expresses a bound for $\Vert T^{-1} \Vert$, for any invertible $n \times n$ real matrix $T$, in terms of a bound for $T$ and a positive lower bound for $\vert \det(T) \vert$, assuming that $T$ is non-singular.  The necessary result will be presented as a brief sequence of lemmas:

***Lemma 1:***  Let $T \in M_n(\Bbb R)$; write

$T = [T_{ij}], 1 \le i, j \le n; \tag{8}$

then if $\Vert T \Vert \le M$, we have

$\vert T_{ij} \vert  \le M \tag{9}$

for every entry $T_{ij}$ of $T$.

***Proof:***  Suppose to the contrary that for some $i, j$ we have $\vert T_{ij} \vert > M$.  Let $T_k$ denote the $k$-th column of $T$; then

$T \mathbf e_j = T_j = \begin{pmatrix} T_{1j} \\T_{2j} \\ \vdots \\ T_{ij} \\ \vdots \\ T_{nj} \end{pmatrix}; \tag{10}$

from (10) we have

$\Vert T \mathbf e_j \Vert^2 = \langle T\mathbf e_j, T\mathbf e_j \rangle = \sum_{l =1}^n \vert T_{lj} \vert^2 = \sum_{l =1, l \ne i}^n \vert T_{lj} \vert^2 + \vert T_{ij} \vert^2 > M^2, \tag{11}$

whence

$M < \Vert T\mathbf e_j \Vert; \tag{12}$

but then

$M < \Vert T \mathbf e_j \Vert \le M \Vert \mathbf e_j \Vert = M; \tag{13}$

this contradiction shows we must indeed have $\vert T_{ij} \vert \le M$, $1 \le i, j \le n$.  ***QED.***

***Lemma 2***:  As in Lemma 1, let $T \in M_n(\Bbb R)$; setting $T = [T_{ij}]$, suppose $\vert T_{ij} \vert \le B$, $0 < B \in \Bbb R$, $1, \le i, j \le n$. Then $\Vert T \Vert \le n^{3/2}B$.

***Proof:***  Pick $u \in \Bbb R^n$, $\Vert u \Vert = 1$; writing

$u = \sum_1^n u_i \mathbf e_i, \tag{14}$

we have

$\Vert Tu \Vert^2 = \vert \Vert Tu \Vert^2 \vert = \vert \langle Tu, Tu \rangle \vert = \vert \langle T(\sum_1^n u_i \mathbf e_i), T(\sum_1^n u_j \mathbf e_j) \rangle \vert$
$= \vert \langle \sum_1^n u_i T\mathbf e_i, \sum_1^n u_j T \mathbf e_j \rangle \vert = \vert \sum_{i, j = 1}^n u_i u_j \langle T\mathbf e_i, T\mathbf e_j \rangle \vert$
$\le \sum_{i, j = 1}^n \vert u_i \vert \vert u_j \vert \vert \langle T\mathbf e_i, T\mathbf e_j \rangle \vert; \tag{15}$

as in Lemma 1, we note that $T\mathbf e_k$ is the $k$-th column of $T$; thus

$\langle T\mathbf e_i, T\mathbf e_j \rangle = \sum_1^n T_{li} T_{lj}; \tag{16}$

also,

$\vert \sum_{l = 1}^n T_{li} T_{lj} \vert \le \sum_{l = 1}^n \vert T_{li} T_{lj} \vert \le \sum_{l = 1}^n B^2 = nB^2; \tag{17}$

combining (16) and (17) yields

$\vert \langle T \mathbf e_i, T\mathbf e_j \rangle \vert \le nB^2; \tag{18}$

thus (15) becomes

$\Vert Tu \Vert^2 \le  \sum_{i,j = 1}^n \vert u_i \vert \vert u_j \vert \vert \langle T\mathbf e_i, T\mathbf e_j \rangle \vert \le \sum_{i, j = 1}^n nB^2 \vert u_i \vert \vert u_j \vert \le \sum_{i, j = 1} nB^2 = n^3 B^2, \tag{19}$

since $\vert u_i \vert, \vert u_j \vert \le 1$ by virtue of the fact that $\sum_1^n u_i^2 = 1$; so

$\Vert Tu \Vert \le n^{3/2} B; \tag{20}$

since (20) holds for any unit vector $u$, we see that

$\Vert T \Vert \le n^{3/2} B \tag{21}$

as well.  ***QED.***

***Lemma 3:***  $T = [T_{ij}]$ as in previous, that is $\vert T_{ij} \vert \le B$ etc.  Then

$\vert \det(T) \vert \le n! B^n. \tag{22}$

***Proof:*** We simply write out the determinant in fully expanded form,

$\det(T) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} (-1)^{\text{sign}(\sigma)} \prod_1^n T_{i \sigma(i)}, \tag{23}$

where $\sigma \in S_n$, the symmetric group on $n$ letters, presented in the form

$\sigma = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & \ldots & n \\ \sigma(1) & \sigma(2) & \ldots & \sigma(n) \end{pmatrix}, \tag{24}$

and $\text{sign}(\sigma)$ is $\pm 1$ according to whether $\sigma$ is an even or odd permutation.  Taking absolute values of (23) yields

$\vert \det(T) \vert = \vert \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} (-1)^{\text{sign}(\sigma)} \prod T_{i \sigma(i)} \vert \le \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \vert \prod_1^n T_{i \sigma(i)} \vert$
$= \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \prod_1^n \vert T_{i \sigma(i)} \vert \le  \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} B^n = n! B^n; \tag{25}$

thus,

$\vert \det(T) \vert \le n! B^n, \tag{26}$

as claimed. ***QED.***

We are working towards preparing an estimate of $\Vert T^{-1} \Vert$ based upon Cramer's rule.  We recall that Cramer's expresses the inverse of $T$, when it exists, i.e. when $\det(T) \ne 0$, as

$T^{-1} = (\det (T))^{-1} \text{adj}(T), \tag{27}$

where $\text{adj}(T)$, the so-called *adjugate matrix* of $T$, is defined as the transpose of $\text{cof}(T)$, the *cofactor matrix* of $T$, which in turn is defined in terms of the minors of $T$ as follows:  we recall that the $k, l$ *minor* of $T$, $m_{kl}(T)$, is the determinant of the submatrix of $T$ resulting from deletion of row $k$ and column $l$ from $T$, and that the $k, l$ *cofactor* is $(-1)^{k + 1}m_{kl}(T)$; then

$\text{cof}(T) = [(-1)^{k + 1}m_{kl}(T)]; \tag{28}$

thus

$\text{adj}(T) = (\text{cof}(T))^T. \tag{29}$

Based upon what we have done so far, it is a relatively straightforward matter to present a bound for $\text{adj}(T)$:

***Lemma 4:***  Again, as in Lemma 3, assuming $T = [T_{ij}]$ with $\vert T_{ij} \vert \le B$,

$\Vert \text{adj}(T) \Vert \le n!\sqrt{n} B^{n - 1}: \tag{30}$

***Proof:***  If we apply Lemma 3 to the $m_{kl}(T)$, it readily follows that

$\vert m_{kl}(T) \vert \le (n - 1)!B^{n - 1}; \tag{31}$

thus every entry $(\text{cof}(T))_{kl}$ of the cofactor matrix of $T$ also satisfies the same bound:

$\vert (\text{cof}(T))_{kl} \vert \le (n - 1)!B^{n -1}; \tag{32}$

by (29), the same is true for the entries of $\text{adj}(T)$; thus by Lemma 2 we have

$\Vert \text{adj}(T) \Vert \le n^{3/2}(n - 1)! B^{n - 1} = n(n - 1)! \sqrt{n} B^{n -1} = n!\sqrt{n} B^{n - 1}. \tag{33}$

***QED.***

Exploiting Lemmas 1-4, we are finally in a position to present an estimate for $\Vert T^{-1} \Vert$ based upon $\Vert T \Vert$ and $\det(T)$:

***Proposition:***  Suppose $\Vert T \Vert \le M$ and $\vert \det(T) \vert \ge m > 0$; then

$\Vert T^{-1} \Vert \le \dfrac{n! \sqrt{n} M^{n - 1}}{m}. \tag{34}$

***Proof:***  By Lemma 1, $\vert T_{ij} \vert \le M$ for $1 \le i, j \le n$; thus by Lemma 4,

$\Vert \text{adj}(T) \Vert \le n!\sqrt{n}M^{n - 1}; \tag{35}$

since

$\vert \det(T) \vert \ge m, \tag{36}$

we have

$\vert \det(T) \vert^{-1} \le \dfrac{1}{m}; \tag{37}$

it now follows from (27) that

$\Vert T^{-1} \Vert = \Vert (\det (T))^{-1} \text{adj}(T) \Vert = \vert \det(T) \vert^{-1} \Vert \text{adj}(T) \Vert$
$\le \dfrac{1}{m} n!\sqrt{n}M^{n - 1} = \dfrac{n!\sqrt{n} M^{n - 1}}{m}. \tag{38}$

***QED.***

***Main Line: Return to Analytics:***  Having developed the bound (34) for $\Vert T^{-1} \Vert$, we return to analysis; we are now on the downhill slope:  since the fundamental matrix $X(t)$ satisfies

$X'(t) = A(t)X(t), \tag{39}$

and that we are given

$ \liminf_{t \rightarrow \infty} \int^t_\beta \text{tr}(A(s))ds > - \infty, \tag{40}$

we are in postion to exploit the well-known fact that

$\dfrac{d\det (X(t))}{dt} = \text{tr}(A(t)) (\det X(t)); \tag{41}$

(41) is widely used in the theory of linear systems of the form (1), (40) and so forth;  see for example the book *Ordinary Differential Equations*, by Jack K. Hale, 2009 Dover Publications, Inc., ISBN-13 978-0-486-47211-6, chapter III, pp. 78-83; see also the linked pages cited by Michael, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential, and Aprilius, [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_formula](http://%5BLiouville%27s%20Formula%5D(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_formula)).  The unique solution to (41) taking the value $\det(X(\beta))$ at $t = \beta$ is

$\det(X(t)) = \det(X(\beta))e^{\int_\beta^t \operatorname{tr}(A(s)) ds}, \tag{42}$

from which it follows that, since $e^{\int_\beta^t \operatorname{tr}(A(s)) ds} > 0$ for all $t \in \Bbb R$,

$\vert \det(X(t)) \vert = \vert \det(X(\beta)) \vert e^{\int_\beta^t \operatorname{tr}(A(s)) ds}. \tag{43}$

Now consider the hypothesis (40); this may be re-stated (see [this wikipedia entry on lim inf, etc.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior)) as

$\lim_{t \to \infty} \inf \{\int_\beta^\tau \operatorname{tr}A(s) ds \ \mid \tau \ge t \} > - \infty; \tag{44}$

for $t_1 \le t_2$ we have the set inclusion

$\{\int_\beta^\tau \operatorname{tr}A(s) ds \ \mid \tau \ge t_2 \} \subset \{\int_\beta^\tau \operatorname{tr}A(s) ds \ \mid \tau \ge t_1 \}; \tag{45}$

define the function $L(t)$ by

$L(t) = \inf \{\int_\beta^\tau \operatorname{tr}A(s) ds \ \mid \tau \ge t \}; \tag{46}$

from (45), we see that $L(t)$ is monotonically increasing, that is

$L(t_1) \le L(t_2) \tag{47}$

for $t_1 \le t_2$.  (This follows from a basic property of sets of real numbers: if $A \subset B \subset \Bbb R$, then $\inf(B) \le \inf(A)$.)  From (40), (44), we have for *some* $t'$ sufficiently large $L(t') > - \infty$; that is, there exists $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ such that

$L(t') = \lambda; \tag{48}$

now (47) implies

$L(t) \ge \lambda \tag{49}$

for $t \ge t'$; for such $t$, by (46),

$\int_\beta^t \operatorname{tr}(A(s))ds \ge \lambda, \tag{50}$

whence

$e^{\int_\beta^t \operatorname{tr}(A(s))ds} \ge e^\lambda; \tag{51}$

then (43) yields

$\vert \det (X(t)) \vert \ge \vert \det (X(\beta)) \vert e^\lambda \tag{52}$

for $t \ge t'$; for $t \in [\beta, t']$, $\int_\beta^t \operatorname{tr}(A(s))ds$, being a continuous function on a compact set, is bounded below by some $\mu \in \Bbb R$, i.e. we have

$\int_\beta^t \operatorname{tr}(A(s))ds \ge \mu; \tag{53}$

thus

$e^{\int_\beta^t \operatorname{tr}(A(s))ds} \ge e^\mu \tag{54}$

on $[\beta, t']$, so that

$\vert \det(X(t)) \vert \ge \vert \det(X(\beta)) \vert e^\mu \tag{55}$

for $\beta \le t \le t'$.  Combining (52) with (55) we may write

$\vert \det (X(t)) \vert \ge \vert \det (X(\beta)) \vert e^{\min(\lambda, \mu)} > 0 \tag{56}$

for $t \in [\beta, \infty]$.

We are now in a position to apply the above proposition with $\Vert X(t) \Vert \le k$ and $\vert \det(X(t)) \vert \ge \ \vert \det X(\beta)) \vert e^{\min(\lambda, \mu)}$ on $[\beta, \infty)$.  We thus immediately see that

$\Vert X^{-1}(t) \Vert \le \dfrac{n! \sqrt{n} k^{n - 1}}{\vert \det(X(\beta)) \vert e^{\min(\lambda, \mu)}}; \tag{57}$

we have now shown that $X^{-1}(t)$ is globally bounded on $[\beta, \infty)$, completing the present answer to the first question (a) our OP Croos here asked.

As for part (b), suppose there were a solution $x(t) \ne 0$ of (1) with $x(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$.  Then since

$x(t) = X(t) x(0), \tag{58}$

we have

$x(0) = X^{-1}(t)x(t); \tag{59}$

since we have proved that $X^{-1}(t)$ is bounded on $[\beta, \infty)$, and it is clearly bounded on $[0, \beta]$, it is in fact globally bounded on $[0, \infty)$; that is, there is $0 < M \in \Bbb R$ with

$\Vert X^{-1}(t) \Vert \le M \tag{60}$

for $t \in [0, \infty)$.  Then

$\Vert x(0) \Vert = \Vert X^{-1}(t) x(t) \Vert \le \Vert X^{-1}(t) \Vert \Vert x(t) \Vert \le M\Vert x(t) \Vert; \tag{61}$

since $x(t) \ne 0$, we must have $x(0) \ne 0$ (this follows from uniqueness of solutions); thus

$\Vert x(0) \Vert \ge \delta \tag{62}$

for some positive $\delta \in \Bbb R$; but taking $t$ sufficiently large, we have

$\Vert x(t) \Vert < M^{-1} \delta; \tag{63}$

then

$\delta \le \Vert x(0) \Vert \le M \Vert x(t) \Vert < M M^{-1} \delta = \delta; \tag{64}$

(64) is a contradiction which in turn precludes $x(t) \to 0$; we have thus established an affirmative result to part (b).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial answer.  Assume $X(t)$ and $A(t)$ are $n \times n$ matrices. Define: 
$$ c = \liminf_{t\rightarrow\infty} \int_\beta^t tr(A(s))ds $$ 
The problem tells us that $c > -\infty$.

1) Note that since $X(t)$ is a solution to $X'(t) = A(t)X(t)$, then for any $n\times n$ matrix $M$ we also get $Y(t) = X(t)M$ is another solution. Let $y_{\beta}$ be any desired initial condition for $Y(\beta)$.  If $X(\beta)$ is invertible, then we can choose $M = X(\beta)^{-1}y_{\beta}$, so that $Y(t)=X(t)M$ is a solution with the desired initial condition $Y(\beta)=y_{\beta}$.

Thus, limiting behavior about $X(t)$ can often be translated to limiting behavior about other solutions $Y(t)$. If $Y(\beta)$ is invertible and $X(t)$ does not approach the zero solution, then $Y(t)$ also does not approach the zero solution. (If $Y(\beta)$ is not invertible then we can have $Y(t)=0$ for all $t$ as a valid solution).

2) Suppose $A(t)$ is a matrix of the form $A(t) = g(t)A$ for some (constant) matrix $A$ and some scalar-valued integrable function $g(t)$.  Then a solution to the ODE is (for $t \geq \beta$):
$$ X(t) = e^{\int_{\beta}^t A(s)ds}X(\beta) \: \: (Equation 1) $$
There are other types of $A(t)$ matrices for which the above solution works, but not all (as pointed out by helpful comments of Robert Lewis above).

Now, the following link gives *Jacobi's formula* for any square matrix $B$: $\det(e^B) = e^{tr(B)}$. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential

Applying this to (Equation 1) gives: 
$$ \det(X(t)) = e^{\int_\beta^ttr(A(s))ds}\det(X(\beta))$$
Taking absolute values of both sides gives: 
$$ |\det(X(t))| = e^{\int_{\beta}^t tr(A(s))ds} |\det(X(\beta))| $$
Taking a $\liminf$ of both sides gives: 
$$ \liminf_{t\rightarrow\infty} |\det(X(t))| = e^{c} |\det(X(\beta))| > 0 $$
where the final inequality holds because we are told that $\det(X(\beta))\neq 0$.  Since the absolute value of the determinant is bounded away from $0$, and since the determinant will be a polynomial function of the entries of the matrix, it follows that the sum of squares of the entries of $X(t)$ must be bounded away from zero.

Answer (score 2):

A quick comment to @Michael's answer: I guess we can apply [Liouville's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_formula) here, which only requires $tr(A(t))$ to be a continuous function. Applying Liouville's Formula gives

$$det(X(t))=det(X(\beta))e^{\int_{\beta}^t tr(A(s))ds},$$

and the rest is given in @Michael 's answer:)

Comment: Wow, I am learning a lot by working on this problem... =)